# Taking a screencast in Backtrack 4

Tags: linux, screencasts

I'm working on a tutorial using Backtrack 4 Live USB, and I would like to take a screencast of what I'm doing (not just screenshots)

So far I have tried these application with limited success:

-recordmydesktop
 -xvidcap
 -wink
 -istanbul
 -vlc
 -vnc2flv

Each time I try the resulting files are generally choppy (at best 1 frame per second) and most don't even end up with a clear view of the screen each time.  If anyone has suggestions for the screencast I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Your problems may stem from the fact that you're using a live environment in trying to create your screencasts. Recording video of your screen is going to need a pretty decent priority. The constant interrupts while reading from the CD is likely to make any video recording choppy.

In summary, sorry, you're out of luck, and you're not going to get a smooth screencast unless you install Backtrack to your hard-drive

Comment: You may lose a bit of some functions that way. I'd suggest a VM and recording from the host OS.

Answer (score 0):

I can't remember if the Backtrack Live USB has a ramdisk option, but that would probably help.